# Why Cakephp's Controller second test case is always failed

Tags: php, cakephp, testcase, phpunit

I'm implementing a controller test case for our application that implemented with cakephp 2.x version.

I have 2 test case so far and planning to do it more. But, I'm stack in second test case and got fail message. If I comment out first test case and run it for second test case, I got the expected result. The only thing is if I have two test case, second test case is always fail. Here is the code snippet for my code.

My running command is `./cake test --stderr app Controller/EventsController` and got error message is `Undefined index: HTTP_HOST`

I knew a bit weird situation that comment out first test case and never get this error and pass successfully for second test case. Appreciate your suggestion and ideas. Thank you so much.

```
App::uses('EventsController', 'Controller');
App::uses('UsersController', 'Controller');

class EventsControllerTest extends ControllerTestCase {
    public function setUp(){
        $this->testAction('/users/login/',[
            'method' => 'POST',
            'data' => [
                'User' => [
                    'username'=> 'bk.ll@llmail.com',
                    'password'=> '123456',
                    'clientType'=>'llWeb'
                ]
            ]
        ]);
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function testEvents(){
        $this->testAction('/admin/events/');
        $this->assertInternalType('array', $this->vars['organisations']);
        $this->assertInternalType('string', $this->vars['userRole']);
        $this->assertInternalType('array', $this->vars['dutyRosterObj']);
        $this->assertInternalType('string', $this->vars['date']);
        $this->assertInternalType('boolean', $this->vars['isKkCdlc']);
    }

    public function testEventsList(){
        $this->testAction('/admin/events/list/');
        $this->assertInternalType('array', $this->vars['events']);
        $this->assertInternalType('array', $this->vars['organisations']);
        $this->assertInternalType('boolean', $this->vars['demoForSchool']);
        $this->assertInternalType('integer', $this->vars['offset']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like You forget to config `$_SERVER` variables in `phpunit.xml.dist` file:

```
<php>
  <server name="HTTP_HOST" value="example.org"/>
</php>
```

More info: https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.3/configuration.html

Comment: Well, as i mentioned in the question and how can I run successfully for second test case if I comment out first test case? If i missed `HTTP_HOST` value, i should able to see the error message if i run second test case right?

Comment: Just wondering, where should I add phpunit.xml.dist in cakephp 2?